# comparison operation in if statment php

Tags: php, arrays

ok i have a lvlcheck.php that compares the players experience and outputs the correct lvl based on experience. yet i cany get it to work. nothing shows up when i echo $lvl. its like all the the statements in lvlcheck.php are failing. 
below is my code.

this is my array to draw user stat experience

```
$sql = 'SELECT a.user, a.' . $stat1 .', b.' . $stat2 .'
    FROM curstats a, experience b
    WHERE a.user = b.user order by ' . $stat2 .' desc LIMIT 15';
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
 array();
$rank = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

   ?>

<tr>
<td align="center"><font color="#d3d3d3"><?php echo $rank++; ?></font></td>
<td align="center"><font color="#d3d3d3"><?php echo $row['user'];?></font></td>
<td align="center"><font color="#d3d3d3"><?php echo $row[$stat2]; ?></font></td>
<td align="center"><font color="#d3d3d3"><?php
  $stat3 = $row['stat2'];   
require 'includes/lvlcheck.php'; 
echo $lvl;  
?></font></td></tr>

 <?php
}  
 ?>
```

and here is my lvl check. code.

```
<?php 
if($stat3 > 0 && $stat3 < 83) {
$lvl = "1";
}
if($stat3 > 83 && $stat3 < 174) {
$lvl = "2";
}
if($stat3 > 174 && $stat3 < 276) {
$lvl = "3";
}
if($stat3 > 276 && $stat3 < 388) {
$lvl = "4";
}
if($stat3 > 388 && $stat3 < 512) {
$lvl = "5";
}
```

i know its the variables $stat1 and $stat2 are being assigned correctly because it will display the right experience just wont convert the the experience into a lvl to output $lvl any idea?

Comment: Looks like you have `$stat3 = $row['stat2'];` instead of `$stat3 = $row[$stat2];`

Comment: good observation and was hoping it would fix it but still didnt do anything lol

Comment: In that case, you'd be upvoted by the OP... seems like they don't do upvoting otherwise, lol.

Comment: what you mean upvoted?

Comment: See those up arrows all over the place?  When people are helpful or otherwise informative you can show your appreciation by clicking those arrows... it encourages people to help you, too.

Answer (score 2):

`< 83` means less than 83, so the highest valid value would be 82

`> 83` means greater than 83, so the lowest valid value would be 84

If you checking for 83, you won't get results.

`<= 83` means less than or equal, so 83 would be included. For example...

Comment: i understand what your saying so i changed it to >= and still nothing

Comment: You realize it's not just 83 that has that issue, it's all of them, right? What is the value you're working with?

Comment: ok lets say $row['$stat2'] = 500 now i assign $stat3= $row]'$stat2']; now i check to see waht lvl 500 is = to  if($stat3 >=0 && $stat3 < 600) { $lvl = "2";}  they way that is writen should make lvl = 2 but it s not working

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove the quotation marks surrounding `$stat2` in `$stat3= $row['$stat2'];`

Now, it reads `$stat3 = $row[$stat2];`.

Comment: @user3078244 Glad you figured it out, but the code that works is the code I posted in my comment.

Comment: well jermemy your did help but idk how to rep you because next to your post its not showing as an answer its showing as a comment on my questions so im not able to check it or rep you.